# Bootstrap - Progress bar as background in card element with anchored percentage

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to recreate something like the image below (the dark one), that looks like a progress bar in every element of a card. I'm getting close but the problem I have so far is that I can't get the percentage value anchored on the right. I think it must be outside of the bar otherwise it moves with it but I don't know how to do it.
Here's what I have so far ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1jw24pe8/3/)):

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
   <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item progress-bar bg-success" style="width:30%; text-align: left; padding-left: 10px;"><a>Cras justo odio<span style="float:right">30%</span></a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item progress-bar bg-info" style="width:100%; text-align: left; padding-left: 10px;">Dapibus ac facilisis in<span style="float:right">100%</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

This is the goal

[image: Progress bar in card]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply give your `.list-group-item`s `position:relative` and place the `.progress` inside them with `position:absolute`.

To place the contents of the `<li>` above the `.progress`, you'll need to wrap it inside an element and give that element `position:relative; z-index: 1` (I used `.content` class in example below, but you might want to change it to something less general).

[See it working](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/vt1qj3u9/).

Relevant CSS:

```css
.list-group-item {
  position: relative;
}

.list-group-item .progress {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.list-group-item .content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

You obviously need to play with the colors, but that's outside of current question's scope.